# NelmioApiDocBundle Support for swagger 2.0

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I work on **symfony 2** project with **NelmioApiDocBundle** **v2.13.0** that dumpthe Swagger-compliant JSON API definitions based on **Swagger 1.2** witch is an old version.
I searched a lot about the NelmioApiDocBundle support for the **Swagger 2.0** but without any good response.
those are tyhe links that i found:

- [twitter 1](https://twitter.com/hashtag/nelmioapidocbundle)
- [twitter 2](https://twitter.com/search?q=NelmioApiDocBundle)
- [gitlab](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/issues/900)

I would like to know if the **NelmioApiDocBundle** support for the **Swagger 2.0**. and if there is another bundle that can replace this bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this [link](https://www.blog.davidfuhr.de/2016/07/12/documentation-driven-api-development-with-swagger.html) i found :

> I had worked with NelmioApiDocBundle before to integrate Swagger with
>   a Symfony application and it is a wonderful tool to document your
>   existing API code. But as NelmioApiDocBundle generates the Swagger
>   file from the annotated source code the source must exist prior to the
>   documentation. This did not match our desired workflow. What’s more,
>   the future of NelmioApiDocBundle seems to be a bit uncertain as the
>   William Durand, the current maintainer, thinks of deprecating the
>   bundle.

William Durand says:

> I am thinking about slowly deprecating #NelmioApiDocBundle
>   (feature-freeze first, then EOL).

[twit](https://twitter.com/couac/status/742266704575758336?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)